# Test externally triggered submit on Formik form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-testing-library

I have a form within a modal that is submitted by clicking the modal save button.

form.js

```
export const FormModal = () => {


  let defaults = {
    description: '',
    sortOrder: '0'
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape(
    Object.keys(defaults)?.reduce(createValidationSchema, {})
  );

  const formRef = useRef();

  /**
   * Save the form
   */
  const onSave = async (values, { setFieldError, setSubmitting }) => {
    // do the save thing
    const result = await addStuff(values);
  };

  /**
   * Handle form submitting from outside button click
   */
  const handleFormSubmit = async () => {
    if (formRef.current) {
      formRef.current.handleSubmit();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      title='Add lookup'
      visible={visible}
      onCancel={closeModal}
      maskClosable={false}
      footer={
        <Modal.Footer>
          <CancelButton key='cancel' onClick={closeModal}>
            Cancel
          </CancelButton>
          <SaveButton key='save' onClick={handleFormSubmit}>
            Save
          </SaveButton>
        </Modal.Footer>
      }
      content={
        <Formik
          initialValues={defaults}
          innerRef={formRef}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={(values, actions) => onSave(values, actions)}
        >
          <Form>
            <FormFields />
          </Form>
        </Formik>
      }
    />
  );
};
```

FormFields.js

```
export const FormFields= () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Box margin={1}>
        <Field
          component={TextField}
          required
          name='description'
          label='Description'
        />
      </Box>

      <Box margin={1}>
        <Field
          component={TextField}
          name='sortOrder'
          label='Sort order'
          required
          type='number'
        />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

The forms works correctly in the browser and submits

FormModal.test.js

```
  it('should submit valid modal', async () => {
    // ARRANGE
    const addStuff = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      status: 200
    });

    // ACT
    render(<FormModal />);
    const description = screen.getByLabelText(/description/i);
    const sortOrder = screen.getByLabelText(/sort order/i);
    const saveButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Save' });

    userEvent.type(description, 'Test description');
    userEvent.type(sortOrder, '1');
    userEvent.click(saveButton);

    // ASSERT
    await waitFor(() => expect(description.value).toBe('Test description'));
    await waitFor(() => expect(sortOrder.value).toBe('1'));
    await waitFor(() => expect(addStuff).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)); // <-- This fails
  });
```

Error:

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

The `addStuff` function is being mocked in the jestSetup.js file. Other test verify this is working fine.

I have also run the debugger with breakpoints in the `handleSubmit` function. It is not being called.

How can I test that the submission was successfull and that the addStuff function was called?

Comment: That `addStuff` mock you have in the test will not mock the `addStuff` used in your component. You mention "The addStuff function is being mocked in the jestSetup.js file", could you share how it's being mocked?

Comment: I would add that the modal itself is also being mocked. ```export const Modal = ({ content, footer, onCancel, title, visible }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {visible && (
        <div data-testid='mockedModal'>
          <div>This is a mocked modal for {title}</div>
          <div data-testid='modalContent'>{content}</div>
          <button data-testid='closeButton' onClick={onCancel}>
            Close
          </button>
          {footer}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: The addStuff mock is ```const addStuff= jest.fn();``` so in the test I have ```addStuff = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      status: 200
    });
```

Comment: I refactored the component to have a wrapper component and moved the save logic into that wrapper.  This way I can move the save event. I was able to test the save logic.